# 14.04 LTS empty boot

Tags: 14.04, boot

I am a novice with software issues and so am asking for what may seem very basic help. I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on 32-bit. I managed to get a list of all that is on my boot, and each time I start my laptop, I get the message that I need to empty disk space in boot as I have 0 bytes space.

So, here is what I have:

```
$ ls /boot/
abi-3.13.0-40-generic     initrd.img-3.13.0-52-generic
abi-3.13.0-43-generic         initrd.img-3.13.0-53-generic
abi-3.13.0-44-generic         lost+found
abi-3.13.0-45-generic         memtest86+.bin
abi-3.13.0-48-generic         memtest86+.elf
abi-3.13.0-49-generic         memtest86+_multiboot.bin
abi-3.13.0-52-generic         System.map-3.13.0-40-generic
abi-3.13.0-53-generic         System.map-3.13.0-43-generic
config-3.13.0-40-generic      System.map-3.13.0-44-generic
config-3.13.0-43-generic      System.map-3.13.0-45-generic
config-3.13.0-44-generic      System.map-3.13.0-48-generic
config-3.13.0-45-generic      System.map-3.13.0-49-generic
config-3.13.0-48-generic      System.map-3.13.0-52-generic
config-3.13.0-49-generic      System.map-3.13.0-53-generic
config-3.13.0-52-generic      vmlinuz-3.13.0-40-generic
config-3.13.0-53-generic      vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic
grub                          vmlinuz-3.13.0-44-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-40-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-45-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-43-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-48-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-44-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-45-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-52-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-48-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-53-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-49-generic
```

What can be done next?

Comment: If you want to keep your older kernels, then we could help you in another way if you could please edit your answer with the output of `sudo fdisk -l`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one thing that can be done is, freeing up some space in your `/boot/` folder by deleting older kernels. Here's how to do it:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-image-3.13.0-40* linux-image-3.13.0-43* linux-image-3.13.0-44* linux-image-3.13.0-45*
```

Then, remove any left-over packages by typing:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean
```